# AngularJS International Phone Number Validation Directive Misbehaving

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have been facing a very puzzling problem with [AngularJS International Phone Number Directive](https://github.com/mareczek/international-phone-number).

I have a form which has an **input** element of type **text** assigned the international-phone-number directive.

Form:

```
<form name="phoneMask" novalidate class="editable-wrap">

      <span class="bold inline-text title" ng-hide="!phone.primary">
            Primary:
      </span>
      <span class="bold inline-text title" ng-hide="phone.primary">
            Alternate:
      </span>


        <span ng-show="!phoneForm.$visible" class="bold title">
            {{phone.telephoneNumber}}
        </span>

        <span ng-show="!phoneForm.$visible">
            ({{showStatus($index).text}})
        </span>
            <div><label ng-show="phoneForm.$visible" class="title" for="natPhone">Phone Number</label><input id="natPhone" ng-show="phoneForm.$visible" type="text" class="editable-input" name="natPhone" international-phone-number utils-script="script/vendor/jquery/libphonenumber-utils.js" ng-model="phone.telephoneNumber" required alt="Phone Number" /></div>

</form>
```

Now the input with id="natPhone" is the input creating problems. I save the number given from user in raw form i.e. without any formatting. The number is automatically formatted by the directive as user types. Problem is when I try to show it on the screen for editing.

**Example:**
The model has the following number: 12015555555. This is a valid US number.
When I click the edit button the above form is shown, which has the input. The input shows the number as it is (12015555555). If I type click on it and press any key; let's say space key or 'a' or anything else, the directive instantly run and formats the number as: +1 201-555-5555.

**Problem Statement:**
I want it to show the formatted number as soon as the edit button is clicked and input element is shown.

**Observations:**
`class` attribute has a different value before pressing any key in the input box, this is also the time when the number is shown non-formatted.
`class="editable-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-valid-required ng-touched"`

Where as when a key is pressed the following value can be seen:
`class="editable-input ng-valid ng-scope ng-valid-required ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-international-phone-number ng-valid-parse"`

**What I have tried:**
1) I have tried JQuery's change() function, but Angular throws $apply is still running error.
2) I have tried to trigger('keypress') event so that it identifies a keypress and format it.

Kindly guide me with your advices.

Comment: Can you craft a plunker demonstrating the issue for this so we can help you out a little bit easier?

Comment: I tried, but I failed to get it working. Tried on Plunker and JSFiddle both.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it, if you can setup a "failed" example, it would be easier to resolve.

Also check for new released version for fixes.

You can set up your own directive to format the number.

```
myModule.directive('phoneHelper', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
        if (!ctrl) {
            return;
        }
        function updateView() {
            var formatters = ctrl.$formatters;
            var idx = formatters.length;
            var value = ctrl.$modelValue;
            while (idx--) {
                value = formatters[idx](value);
            }
            if (ctrl.$viewValue !== value) {
                ctrl.$viewValue = value;
                ctrl.$render();
            }
        }

        scope.$on('editButtonClicked',updateView)
        //element.on('blur', updateView);
    }
}
```

});